# My Throttable EventStream implementation - is it redundant?

Tags: frp, bacon.js

**Subject**: I have a stream (actually combined stream from Bacon.interval and buttons clicks EventStreams) wich fires ajax request and solve task of manual and automatic data refresh.

**Problem**: After manual events (buttons clicks) I need reset timer because two immediate updates looks ugly.

**My solution**: I've created my own Bacon.interval implementation where event polls can be reseted http://jsfiddle.net/cvvkxveq/1/:

```
    Bacon.dynInterval = function(time,resetter){
    if(!time) return Bacon.once(new Bacon.Error("Invalid args"));
    var ivId, lastTime = Date.now();
    return time < 1 ? Bacon.once(new Bacon.Error("Invalid time")) : Bacon.fromBinder(function(sink) {
      function setUpInterval(){
        if(ivId) clearInterval(ivId);
        ivId = setInterval(function(){
          var n = Date.now();
          var tdx = n - lastTime;
          lastTime = n;
          sink(new Bacon.Next(tdx));
        },time);
      }
      setUpInterval();
      if(resetter) resetter.onValue(setUpInterval);

      return function() {
        clearInterval(ivId);
        sink(new Bacon.End())
      }
    })
  }
```

**Question**: Is such behaivour can be done without custom event stream?

**Update (thanks *@raimohanska*'s answer)** basing on *@raimohanska*'s answer I've also converded my ouUiE event sream (manualTriggerE) to property with initial value to accomplish immediate updates starts.

```
var quotesService = Bacon.constant({url:"quotes.php"});
var onUiE = $("#next_stock, #prev_stock, #refresh_quotes").clickE().map(".currentTarget.id");
var onUiP = onUiE.toProperty("");
var periodicUpdateE = onUiP.flatMapLatest(function(){ return Bacon.interval(3000)});
var manualPlusPeriodicP = onUiP.toEventStream().merge(periodicUpdateE);
var quotesStream = quotesService.sampledBy(manualPlusPeriodicP).ajax();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a stream `manualTriggerE`, you can add periodic updates that are reseted on each manual trigger like this:

```
let periodicUpdateE = manualTriggerE.flatMapLatest(() => Bacon.interval(1000))
let manualPlusPeriodicE = manualTrigger.merge(periodicUpdateE)
```

The trick is `flatMapLatest`: it restarts the periodic updates whenever a manual trigger occurs.